# Bit operations in Lua

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation

I try to parse `gpx` files and to output `encoded polylines` ([Google algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm))

**test.gpx**

```
    <trkseg>
                <trkpt lon="-120.2" lat="38.5"/>
                <trkpt lon="-120.95" lat="40.7"/>
                <trkpt lon="-126.453" lat="43.252"/>
    </trkseg>
```

I managed most of it, but have trouble with encoding the numbers

**gpx2epl:**

```
file = io.open(arg[1], "r")
io.input(file)
--
function round(number, precision)
   return math.floor(number*math.pow(10,precision)+0.5) / math.pow(10,precision)
end

function encodeNumber(number)
  return number
end
--
local Olatitude = 0
local Olongitude = 0
--
while true do
  local line = io.read()
  if line == nil 
  then 
    break 
  end
  if string.match(line, "trkpt") then
    local latitude
    local longitude
    local encnum
    latitude = string.match(line, 'lat="(.-)"')
    longitude = string.match(line, 'lon="(.-)"')
    latitude = round(latitude,5)*100000
    longitude = round(longitude,5)*100000
    encnum = encodeNumber(latitude-Olatitude)
    print(encnum)
    encnum = encodeNumber(longitude-Olongitude)
    print(encnum)
    Olatitude = latitude
    Olongitude = longitude
  end
end
```

This script produces the expected output (see: Google Link), with the exception of encoded latitude and longitude.

```
3850000
-12020000
220000
-75000
255200
-550300
```

[Mapquest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/common/encodedecode.html) provides an implementation in Javascript:

```
function encodeNumber(num) {
   var num = num << 1;
   if (num < 0) {
      num = ~(num);
   }
   var encoded = '';
   while (num >= 0x20) {
      encoded += String.fromCharCode((0x20 | (num & 0x1f)) + 63);
      num >>= 5;
   }
   encoded += String.fromCharCode(num + 63);
   return encoded;   
}
```

Can this be done in Lua? Can somebody please help me out. I have no idea how to implement this in Lua.

**Edit:**

Based on Doug's advice, I did:

```
function encodeNumber(number)
  local num = number
  num = num * 2
  if num < 0
  then
    num = (num * -1) - 1
  end
  while num >= 32
  do
    local num2 = 32 + (num % 32) + 63
    print(string.char(num2))
    num = num / 32
  end
  print(string.char(num + 63) .. "\n-----")
end

encodeNumber(3850000)   -- _p~iF
encodeNumber(-12020000) -- ~ps|U
encodeNumber(220000)    -- _ulL
encodeNumber(-75000)    -- nnqC
encodeNumber(255200)    -- _mqN
encodeNumber(-550300)   -- vxq`@
```

It's near expected output, but only near ... Any hint?

Comment: lua 5.2 contains a bit32 library, luajit also contains bit operations, luabitop exists for use with lua 5.1

Comment: What is the expected output for your 6 numbers? They look correct; are you simply having trouble concatenating the characters?

Comment: @DougCurrie The expected output is on Goggle's website and I've added them in my edit behind encodeNumber calls!

Comment: @DougCurrie Seems to be some kind of rounding problem. The output is sometimes wrong by 1. `encodeNumber(-75000)` should produce `nnqC` but does `nnqD`.

Comment: I get nnqC using my function below.

Comment: @DougCurrie Really, that's strange. Here i still get `nnqD` both with `Lua 5.1.5 (Cygwin)` and `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (rev 4971)`, which is `texlua` from my `TeXLive` distribution.

Comment: @Josef - I am using Lua 5.2. I added `math.floor` to the code below; please see if it helps.

Comment: @DougCurrie Thank you very much, your algorithm is much easier to understand! This is a great benefit for my `getmap` LaTeX package. No need to encode the polyline on a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking `encodeNumber` piecemeal...

```
   var num = num << 1;
```

This is just `num = num * 2`

```
   num = ~(num);
```

This is `num = (- num) - 1`

```
   0x20 | (num & 0x1f)
```

Is equivalent to `32 + (num % 32)`

```
   num >>= 5
```

Is equivalent to `num = math.floor(num / 32)`

ADDENDUM

To concatenate the characters, use a table to collect them:

```
function encodeNumber(number)
  local num = number
  num = num * 2
  if num < 0
  then
    num = (num * -1) - 1
  end
  local t = {}
  while num >= 32
  do
    local num2 = 32 + (num % 32) + 63
    table.insert(t,string.char(num2))
    num = math.floor(num / 32) -- use floor to keep integer portion only
  end
  table.insert(t,string.char(num + 63))
  return table.concat(t)
end
```

Comment: I took your advice to implement `encodeNumber`, but there seems to be still a problem. I get almost the expected output but only almost. See my edit.

Comment: @Josef - the divide operation can produce fractional results, so I just added a floor operation to keep num an integer.